# XCode 6.1.1 UITableView White Spacing Gap

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

I have been running into some issues where my UITableView after being dragged and dropped into my view controller appears with a sizable white space gap from the top of the element ot the start of the prototype cells. Why does this occur by default and is there a way to remove this? Maybe in the size inspector?

[image: prototype cells]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue in 6.3.2 and all I had to do was to go to the ViewController's attribute inspector and uncheck the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in the layout information section.

Sorry, they won't let me post images, but that solved the frustration for me. Hope it helps someone else.